# jQuery - Can access an element's class on one line, can't on the next

Tags: jquery

This is from a section of a much more complicated script. In short, I'm trying to do 2 things here:

1. Get an element's children's class names, and remove the word "span" from them, then add them to a variable (this works fine).
2. Get those class names (in full, with 'span' still attached) and add them to an array.

Here's my code:

```
var currentSpans = [];

$('container').children().each(function(i2, spans) {
    if (spans.className.indexOf('span') != -1) {
        total += parseInt(spans.className.replace(/[A-Za-z$-]/g, ""),10);
        currentSpans.push(spans.attr('class'));
    }

});
```

It breaks at `currentSpans.push(spans.attr('class'));` and says `#<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'attr'`

```
        currentSpans.push(spans.className());
```

as it was used above, but here it doesn't work (this was expected though).

What am I doing wrong here? It seems like a simple enough problem but I'm coming up blank, might be because I've been working with jquery all day!

Comment: className is not a jQuery method, so it works on the native javascipt element, but attr() is a jQuery method and does not work on the native javascript element, but on a jQuery object. You could just do `currentSpans.push(spans.className);` without the parenthesis, as it's not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spans.attr('class')` should be `$(spans).attr('class')`.

When you are accessing `spans.className` you are using the dom object reference, `attr()` is not a method of the dom object but a method provided by jQuery so you need to use the jQuery reference to that element by using `$(spans)`.

Updated:

```
$('.row-fluid').each(function (i, ele) {
    var total = 0;
    var currentSpans = [];

    $(ele).children().each(function (i2, spans) {
        var className = $(spans).attr('class');
        var spanClass = /span\d+/.exec(className);
        spanClass = spanClass.length > 0 ? spanClass[0] : undefined;
        if (spanClass) {
            total += parseInt(spanClass.replace("span", ""), 10);
            currentSpans.push(spanClass);
        }

    });

    console.log(currentSpans, total);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Rhdx3/3/):

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. However, it's still not working; `   currentSpans.push($(spans).attr('class'));` gives " Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'attr' " which seems...odd.

Comment: Can you share the markup? Looks like your script might be cached, Can you try by clearing the cache

Comment: After pressing refresh a few more times you seem to be correct. HOWEVER the array is still empty - nothing is being pushed into it. Code is pretty much exactly as written above, except with your `currentSpans.push($(spans).attr('class'))` addendum

Comment: Can you share the HTML used? It seems to be working here http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/JftMC/1/

Comment: It's pretty big in all, but you get the idea here: http://jsfiddle.net/Rhdx3/1/ (apologies for the lack of css, ignore the preview window!) basically I'm building a plugin for Bootstrap that adds fluidity and I want to test whether the child spans of a `.row-fluid` add up to more than 12 (max spans in a responsive row for bootstrap is 12)

Comment: What is the `container`? is it a class? I'm not finding it anywhere. and what is the desired o/p?

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified. `container` was just a placeholder for this question. the real element I'm selecting is `.row-fluid`.

Comment: In that case http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Rhdx3/2/ seems to be working, it is giving total as 9, 12 and 12

Comment: Oh what! I'm an idiot, for some reason left a `$('container')` selector in there. Cheers for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery's [`each()` function](http://api.jquery.com/each/) gives you two arguments in the callback function, the index and the element. This element is not yet a jQuery object and hence doesn't contain the `attr()` function.

In order to convert it into a jQuery object al lyou have to do is wrap it with brackets and put the jQuery selector before. So `spans` becomes `$(spans)`.

Within an `each()` callback, you can also use `$(this)` to reference the current item.

`spans.className` worked for you because `className` is a native JavaScript property.